# Dealing with empty lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `A,B` and I am mapping the values using `map()` as shown below. This works fine when both the lists have elements. However, when `A,B` are both empty, I get an error. I also present the expected output.

```
A=[]
B=[]
tol=1e-12

CA, CB = map(list, zip(*((a, b) for a, b in zip(B, A) if a[0]>tol)))

print(CA)
print(CB)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    CA, CB = map(list, zip(*((a, b) for a, b in zip(B, A) if a[0]>tol)))

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

The expected output is

```
CA=[]
CB=[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if len(A) == 0 or len(B) == 0:
    CA = []
    CB = []
else:
    CA, CB = map(list, zip(*((a, b) for a, b in zip(A, B) if a[0] > tol)))
```